# Difference between get() and all() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What is difference between these two in laravel

```
$input = Input::get();
```

And

```
$input = Input::all();
```

And which one i should prefer.

Comment: I personally think that one should always know where their input is coming from.

Comment: well for example if a form is submitted both will get the data posted. but why they have made two different methods. There must be something that they have made two methods for this. so i want to know difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taken from the laravel source:

```
public static function all()
{
   $input = array_merge(static::get(), static::query(), static::file());
   // ....
   return $input;
}
```

So `all()` calls `get()` and returns it's contents along with `query()`, and `file()` the $_FILES superglobal.

Preference will obviously depend on circumstance. I personally choose to use `Input::get($key, $default)` as I usually know what I am after.

Comment: so you mean to say that the get does not include files array. while all has files array. So i should use all if there are file uploads and get when there is no file upload just simple data.

Comment: To quote the code again, `Input::get()`: *This method is used for all request verbs (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE)* - So no, it does not include $_FILES. There is however `Input::file($key, $default)` if you know the file you are after.

Answer (score 3):

From the Laravel Manual: http://laravel.com/docs/input

Retrieve a value from the input array:

```
$email = Input::get('email');
```

Note: The "get" method is used for all request types (GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE), not just GET requests.

Retrieve all input from the input array:

```
$input = Input::get();
```

Retrieve all input including the $_FILES array:

```
$input = Input::all();
```

By default, null will be returned if the input item does not exist. However, you may pass a different default value as a second parameter to the method:

Comment: It looks like this link is broken. What version were you viewing this on? Still +1 because you added info from the page, which too many answerers do not do.